# Wordpress Pagination - Paged returns Empty Page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a pagination function, that shows the page number correctly, however upon clicking on next page e.g 2 it simple shows a white blank page, no matter what I do, I tried doing all possible options to atleast show me the error, but nothing at all.. I have a pagination function that's work perfectly when I used that in shortcodes.. but in any page, if I pass page.php?page_id=1&paged=2 anywhere paged=2 in GET, it shows blank page...

the structure of pages is like this:

index.php has the following code..

```
 get_header();  
 get_template_part( 'templates/_content' );
 get_footer();
```

and in _content.php template file, I have following code..

```
if(is_home() OR is_category()) {

    global $paged, $wp_query;
    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

    $posts_per_page = 2;
    $options = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
      'paged'          => $paged,
      'post_status'    => 'publish'
    );

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($options);
    $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    $custom_pagination = custom_pagination($pages,$posts_per_page);
    if($wp_query->have_posts()) : 
        while($wp_query->have_posts()) : the_post();
            get_template_part( 'templates/blog_archive_template' );     
        endwhile;
    else:
        echo '
            <h2 class="center">Not Found !</h2>
            <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn\'t here.</p>';
    endif; 

    echo $custom_pagination;

} else {    
  if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
  /* rest of html code */
}
```

Can someone please point out single thing that would help me. Thanks for your time.

regards

Comment: Try enabling wp debug and check error_log for any hints

Comment: Thanks Hassan, I have them in my wp-config unfortunately..

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: I tried adding die("this this text"); one line in index.php and it shows fine, but if I add &paged=2 it shows blank white page... but with &paged=1 shows this text.. I am really tired or fighting with this, been almost a week now..

Comment: Do you have a 404.php in your theme? It sounds like the white page may be because it's displaying the 404 template which is empty/broken.

Comment: OMG - Nathan. how could I leave that page as blank :( its been week am trying to find because of my limited knowledge in WP... THANKS A MILLION... now I can continue from there.. thanks...

Comment: Pleased I could help! :) In my answer I explain why it's showing 404.php and not a second page of posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default posts per pages will be 10. You've set it to 2 inside your custom query but by that point WordPress has already determined that there's no need for a page 2 and is instead showing the 404 template.

You need to modify the main query using `pre_get_posts` instead.

Example:

```
/**
 * Modify the main query on the posts index or category 
 * page. Set posts per page to 2.
 *
 * @param object $query
 */
function wpse_modify_home_category_query( $query ) {

    // Only apply to the main loop on the frontend.
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() {
        return false;
    } 

    // Check we're on a posts or category page.
    if ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_category() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_modify_home_category_query' );
```

Once you've added this to `functions.php` Remove your custom query from the `index.php` template and use the regular loop.

If the only thing that's changing is the number of posts per page and it should apply globally then you'd be better off changing the value in the admin panel on the Settings -> Reading page.

Comment: Nathan - YOU ROCK... you also solved the problem ahead, I would have wasted more time finding solution... THANKS A LOT... highly appreciated.. cheers